# How to extract files from older commits?

Tags: git

How do I get the original report file out from the first commit "Original report", without losing the current possition of the commits?

```
$ git log
commit 8ad11e4940d81bc33f8d0e19cad6007e632e7434 (HEAD -> master)
Author: Oshirowanen
Date:   Wed Jan 31 11:08:18 2018 +0000

    Modified Date column to show NA if date is missing

commit 00cb9757d432e4dd425ff33af90ed25c91102914
Author: Oshirowanen
Date:   Wed Jan 31 09:31:41 2018 +0000

    Added 1 column, removed 4 columns

commit d7e111384e04b52464edda76bcfd24693b89509
Author: Oshirowanen
Date:   Wed Jan 31 09:27:03 2018 +0000

    Original report

Oshirowanen@Desktop MINGW64 /c/Users/Oshirowanen/Documents/Reports/Report 1 (master)
$
```

Comment: Use [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`git show` can do that:

```
$ git show d7e111384e0:relative/path/to/the/file > where/to/save/the/file
```

Here, the general form of the command is `git show REVISION:path`,
the `>` is a shell's stream redirection operator which redirects
the output of `git show` to the specified file.

The details about the syntax are in the `gitrevisions` manual page:

> `<rev>:<path>`, e.g. `HEAD:README`, `:README`, `master:./README`
>
> A suffix `:` followed by a path names the blob or tree at the given path in the tree-ish object named by
>   the part before the colon.  `:path` (with an empty part before the colon) is a special case of the syntax
>   described next: content recorded in the index at the given path. A path starting with `./` or `../` is
>   relative to the current working directory. The given path will be converted to be relative to the
>   working tree’s root directory. This is most useful to address a blob or tree from a commit or tree that
>   has the same tree structure as the working tree.

Use the `git help revisions` command to read it.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`git checkout`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-checkout):

```
git checkout d7e1113 -- "Report 1"
```

*(Replace `"Report 1"` in the command above with the path of the file you want to get.)*

The command updates the index and the working copy for file "Report 1" with the version of it as it was in commit `d7e1113` (subject "Original report").